# Google reCaptcha validation (siteverify) time out

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to validate Google reCaptcha on my website (I am using godaddy server (cpanel)). But when I try to verify server side, it takes too long, and and then I get a time out.

Can anyone point out what is causing the problem?

```
if(isset($this->data['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($this->data['g-recaptcha-response'])){              
    $u  = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".DataSecret."&response=".$this->data['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response = @file_get_contents($u);
    $arr = json_decode($response,true);
}
```

I get this error message:

> Warning (2): file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={XXXXXXXXXX}&response={XXXXXXXXXXXX}&remoteip=xxx.x.xx.xx): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

*NOTE:* On local host (which is on the same server), `file_get_contents` is working. I just have issue with recaptcha.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I've found out that my server do not connect (timeout) to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify by using the ip address resolved by the OS ( but it works in my client ). I think google server blacklisted my server IP. I did a workaround by using a different IP for google server (editing my server /etc/hosts file) and I'm waiting tomorrow to remove this entry and fin out if problem still there.

Comment: @Luma in my case that was server issue .. maybe that shared hosting have some firewall issue .. I used other server and it was working fine.  so no issue with coding. :)

Answer (score 2):

@Yogesh Saroya,
               Have you checked `allow_url_fopen=On`, `allow_url_include=On` in your server settings? I think these two settings are required.

Comment: Yes both are on but in my case that was server issue .. maybe that shared hosting have some firewall issue .. I used other server and it was working fine. so no issue with coding. :)

Comment: Do you have found any solution?

Comment: Could you share what the server issue was please? I think I'm having the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: I also had the same problem. It just suddenly started. Luckily I noticed it after a few hours, so I could reboot the server and it was fixed. But I'm curious how to find the cause and prevent this in the future.

Comment: @Toton Yes it was server issue. it was shared hosting